# Windows 10 development environment evaluation VHD

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, vhd, visual-studio-2017

I navigated to https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/virtual-machines and downloaded WinDev1709Eval.HyperV.zip but it turned out to be Version 10.0.15063 (rs2) instead of Fall Creators Update as advertised on the page... Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: What I downloaded was 1709.

Comment: @Ramhound I was referring to the version of Windows actually contained in the vhd... Can you post the resolved url for the download?

Comment: As was I talking about which version of Windows was installed on the virtual hdd.